# Can't access Windows after linux mint update

Tags: windows-7, multi-boot, linux-mint, grub2

I have a dual boot system with Windows 7 and linux mint. I recently updated my mint distro by installing the new version (in the process eliminating the older version.) I can now use linux mint fine but can't get into Windows at all. I have tried updating the grub bootloader but can't seem to get anything to work.

Comment: Do you mean you can't boot into windows or you can't see the windows partition from Linux? If its a boot problem, try booting from a windows install disc, go into repair console and fix the boot manager. This will wipe out grub, but which when you re-install (again) will finally recognize the windows boot.

Answer (score 0):

Try boot-repair-- it fixes problems just like yours.
http://www.howtogeek.com/114884/how-to-repair-grub2-when-ubuntu-wont-boot/

HTH

Comment: Super User's purpose is to build a knowledgebase rather than a collection of links to answers elsewhere.  External links can fail or be unavailable, in which case your answer would have no value.  Please include the essential information in your answer and use the link for attribution and further reading.  Thanks.